# LibreOffice 4.2 PPA archive size?

Tags: linux-mint, libreoffice

Can anyone give me an idea of the total download size for LibreOffice 4.2 PPA?

Am using Mint 14 Nadia (Ubuntu 12.10)

Current LO version 3.6.2.2 from the repo, and I have a problem with this bug, where conditional formatting seems to be causing a crash, so I want to upgrade. But I am on a restricted traffic connection, hence would like to know the archive size in advance (unavailable on LO PPA site, AFAICS).

Answer (score 1):

You will find detailed information about PPA packages using the link in the upper right corner of the [PPA's overview](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa):

---

[image: details link]

---

On the [package details page](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa/+packages), you'll find information about the size of the complete archive, as well as details of the single packages:

---

[image: package details]

---

EDIT:

You may have to activate JavaScript in your browser - it seems the package totals are calculated only if JavaScript is available.

Comment: Thanks, but that returns;

Package totals
The following information is related to the total published packages in the repository (not on your system).

Package counters and estimated archive size temporarily unavailable.

Comment: I've just checked https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-4-2/+packages, and it works fine for me. You may have to activate JavaScript on the launchpad site - it seems the package totals are calculated only if JavaScript is available.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need an exact size, you can have a look at [LibreOffice download page](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/?type=deb-x86_64&version=4.2) - their Linux installer has around 200MB, but includes most of the generally available libraries you may (or may not) have already installed - the reason is that it strives to run on a general Linux distribution so it needs to fit a reasonable low common denominator.

On the other hand, [Slackware package](http://www.slackware.com/~alien/slackbuilds/libreoffice/pkg64/14.1/) (conveniently in a single file) has a bit over 100MB.

Hence expect something in between, depending on how many dependencies which won't require updating you already have installed, and add ~4MB per localization package.